# Qt Installer Framework: Translate component description

Tags: qt, internationalization, installation, translate, qt-installer

I've got Qt Installer Framework QtIFW2.0.1 installed and I had a look at the shipped examples.
When I had a closer look at the example *translations* I learned how I can translate the content of a custom ui file. But what I neither saw in the example nor in the documentation is how I can translate text that is located in the component *package.xml* file.
In the above mentioned example this looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
    <DisplayName>The root component</DisplayName>
    <Description>This component contains a license and translations to German.</Description>
    <Version>0.5.0-1</Version>
    <ReleaseDate>2015-01-29</ReleaseDate>
    <Licenses>
        <License name="Beer Public License Agreement" file="license.txt" />
    </Licenses>
    <Default>true</Default>
    <Script>installscript.qs</Script>
    <UserInterfaces>
        <UserInterface>page.ui</UserInterface>
    </UserInterfaces>
    <Translations>
        <Translation>de.qm</Translation>
        <Translation>pl.qm</Translation>
    </Translations>
</Package>`

So, long story short: How can I translate this particular text-line:
`<Description>...</Description>`
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple:

```
<Description>Miam-Player is the main program. It is required and cannot be unselected.</Description>
<Description xml:lang="fr_fr">Miam-Player est le programme principal. Il est requis et ne peut être désélectionné.</Description>
```

I don't think you need something else.

Comment: Works like a charm for package files, but will result in an error if used for the `config.xml`. The error is `Caught exception: Error in ./config/config.xml, line 4, column 24: Element 'Name' has been defined before.` - Is there a way to do it in the config file too?

Comment: @Michael alright. Maybe you could accept this answer then?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe only in IFW 3.0, but in my case it worked.

To specify localization of "DisplayName", you need to use 5-character name of language, and for "Desctiption" you need to use language name of 2 letters

```
<DisplayName>The root component</DisplayName>
<DisplayName xml:lang="ru_RU">Корневой компонент</DisplayName>
<Description>Miam-Player is the main program. It is required and cannot be unselected.</Description>
<Description xml:lang="ru">Miam-Player это основная программа. Она необходима и не может быть отменена</Description>
```