# Change qt installer language at runtime

Tags: qt, installation

I have created an installer for our application using QT installer framework. Now we want to add multi language feature to our installer. I created a page which contains a combobox that allows user to select the language to use during the installation but I do not know how to change the language at runtime using script file. Has anyone had the same experience.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/4115/dynamic-language-translation-in-qt/2 works fine for Qt5

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my problem is I do not have access to the cpp files. I am looking for a way to be able change language in the script file(installer.js)

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qt-installer-framework-translations-example.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349783/qt-installer-framework-translate-component-description